# How can I add MPT support to elementary OS to read files from an Android phone?

Tags: mtp

I connected my Android phone (an xperia z5 (android nougat 7.1.1)) in elementary OS Juno. However, when I attempt to open files on the device using the Files application, I get the following error:

> Cannot open file with this protocol (mtp)

This happens regardless of file type (jpg, mp3, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's because, unfortunately, Elementary OS ships without MTP support. MTP is the protocol Android uses to share files with a desktop OS.

There was a ppa called `ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`, but it seems to have gone offline. That means it will be challenging to get your Android phone to work well with the Files app.

There is another solution, however less elegant. Open AppCenter and search for **gmtp**. gmtp is a special application designed just for downloading and uploading files to and from mp3 players and mobile phones. It might be what you need.